# Getting domain name without TLD

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this code right here:

```
    // get host name from URL
    preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',
    "http://www.joomla.subdomain.php.net/index.html", $matches);
    $host = $matches[1];

    // get last two segments of host name
    preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
    echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

The output will be `php.net`

I need just `php` without `.net`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the first part of your 2nd regex into `/([^.]+)\.[^.]+$/` and `$matches[1]` will be php

Answer (score 7):

Although regexes are fine here, I'd recommend [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse-url)

```
$host = parse_url('http://www.joomla.subdomain.php.net/index.html', PHP_URL_HOST);
$domains = explode('.', $host);
echo $domains[count($domains)-2];
```

This will work for TLD's like .com, .org, .net, etc. but not for .co.uk or .com.mx. You'd need some more logic (most likely an array of tld's) to parse those out .

Answer (score 1):

Late answer and it doesn't work with subdomains, but it does work with any `tld` (co.uk, com.de, etc):

```
$domain = "somesite.co.uk";
$domain_solo = explode(".", $domain)[0];
print($domain_solo);
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/owy3es)

Answer (score -2):

It's really easy:

```
function get_tld($domain) {
    $domain=str_replace("http://","",$domain); //remove http://
    $domain=str_replace("www","",$domain); //remowe www
    $nd=explode(".",$domain);
    $domain_name=$nd[0];
    $tld=str_replace($domain_name.".","",$domain);
    return $tld;
}
```

To get the domain name, simply `return  $domain_name`, it works only with top level domain. In the case of subdomains you will get the subdomain name.