# Take url and parse out a part of it

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting domain name without TLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760797/getting-domain-name-without-tld)

So I have a Web site I am trying to work on. In the URL there is info and I want to parse it out and use it to make a db call to mysql:

http://www.relevant-info.org/home.html

I want to take the Url put it into a string.

Then I want to only get 'relevant-info'  out of the url.

```
$webaddress = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$parts = parse_url($webaddress);
$url = substr($Parts, 4, -4);
```

^ i am using that and I got the ip address (it is a centos 5.8 lamp) on a VM i am testing this, so in short this seams to work good so far :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php p.s. typing "Take url and parse out a part of it php" (your question's title + php appended) into Google will answer your question immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to **Relentless**

You can easily find it with the PHP parse-url function: [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Example usage: If you want to get 'relevant-info', a **PHP 5.4** valid code could look like:

```
$Url = substr(parse_url("http://www.relevant-info.org/home.html")[1], 4, -4);
```

Output

> relevant-info

**For PHP 5.3 and less**

```
$Parts = parse_url("http://www.relevant-info.org/home.html");
$Url = substr($Parts, 4, -4);
```

In future situtations, if you do not have fancy functions like parse-url, you can use **Regex** or use str_split

Remember that str_split requires less resources

Comment: so but I want to pull from the page this script will be on the url. How do I get the URL from the page I am on?

Comment: That is located inside the $_SERVER array

Comment: In other words: $current_URL = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

Answer (score 0):

I have another great idea!

What about explode?

```
var_dump(explode('.', 'http://www.relevant-info.org/home.html'));
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "http://www"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "relevant-info"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "org/home"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "html"
}
```

Comment: Consider this url: http://www.somewebsite.webs.com/

Comment: it doesn't work with subdomains as I wrote in my last post. The definition what need to work and what not is bad :) So here is a bad answer ;) btw "THE ANSWER" doesn't do this too :)

Answer (score -1):

parse_url won't help, because it doesn't split the domain.

I would suggest a regex. Depending wether you are using only www subdomains something like:

`preg_match(#http(s)?://(www.)?(.+?)\..*#, $subject, $matches)`

`$matches[3]` should contain the subdomain of the TLD