# Why is parse_url returning null?

Tags: php

I know this is a simple question. But I can't really seem to understand why this function is returning null. I am trying to just the url host, and it returns null. In the example below i passed google.com.. I am trying to return an array where it just says "google"

Also when I pass in http://www.google.com it just "www.google.com"

Below is my code

```
    $test = parse_url("google.com",PHP_URL_HOST);


    var_dump($test);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `google.com` isn't a URL. It's lacking a scheme (i.e. `https://`). If you look at the output of `parse_url("google.com")`, it is thus being handled like it were a relative URL, with `google.com` being the `path` component of that URL.

Answer (score 3):

`parse_url` normally returns an array of components. If one of the components cannot be determined, it is set to null. The second argument will allow you to get a specific component without having to pull it out of the array.

By passing in `PHP_URL_HOST` you're requesting the `host` part of the parse_url array. It is returning null because `google.com` isn't a valid URL so it can't determine the host; it is missing the protocol (in the case of google.com, `https://`).

In the case that you pass `https://www.google.com` it will return `www.google.com` because that is the host domain. If you want to always get `google` regardless of protocol, and regardless of subdomain, you'll need to do more than pass it through `parse_url` as there isn't any component that does what you want.

You'd be looking for something along the lines of what is asked in this question:
[Getting domain name without TLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760797/getting-domain-name-without-tld)

Answer (score -2):

```
function getHost($Address) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
   return trim($parseUrl['host'] ? $parseUrl['host'] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl['path'], 2))); 
} 

getHost("example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("http://example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("www.example.com"); // Gives www.example.com 
getHost("http://example.com/xyz"); // Gives example.com
```

Comment: Is this an answer or are you trying to provide additional information to your question?

Comment: This code doesn't work. `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host` and `PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference`.